# Updating HTML inside async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I am trying to update the Html inside the GET function. When I print it right after request.onload, the content is updated, however, outside the function it remains the same:

```
function locationData(zip_code)
{
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.send();
  request.onload = () =>
  
  {
     if (request.status == 200) 
     {
        data = JSON.parse(request.response);
        document.getElementById("forecast").innerHTML = "Upadted content";
        console.log(document.getElementById("forecast").innerText); // **Updated content**
        
     }
     else {(console.log("error"));} 
  }
  console.log(document.getElementById("forecast").innerText); //**Old content**
} 
console.log(document.getElementById("forecast").innerText); //**Old content**


window.onload = function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("forecast")); 
    
    }
```

I suspect that async function doesn't stop on time when Updated content is requested. That is why I'm trying window.onload, but still not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: outside the onload callback, nothing changes until onload callback is called

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. How do I call onload? I thought I was already doing it...

Comment: yes, you are doing it - my comment remains

Answer (score 0):

This is all as expected, maybe if you visualize like this:

```
locationData() {
  // now (== when locationData is called)
  // now
  // now
  request.onload = () => {
    // future
    // future
    // future
  }
  // now
  // now 
  // now
}
```

You simply have to give up on using data that only will be available in the future. If you want to do something with data in the future, then you must put that logic in the future as well.

And you alread update (`....innerHTML = something`) in the future, so your code probably works as expected, except for the console.logs of course.

Just be aware that if you log an object in the browser console, you will see it's current state, and not "when" it was logged. It's a pitfall, but convenient when you know how it works.  you can `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))` to make sure you see the object as it was when it was logged.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I need to use the updated content further in the code, how can I access it then?